Incremental columns in revealjs quarto
I have a two column layout slide with some bullet points in revealjs Quarto. Now I would like to incremental show the columns. This means first show the left column and next the right column. When we create columns we use .column and for incremental we use .incremental. Unfortunately we can't combine these somehow:
---
format: revealjs
---

# Example slide

::: columns
::: {.column width="50%"}

- Eat spaghetti
- Drink wine

:::

::: {.column width="50%"}

- Drink coffee
- Eat a hamburger

:::
:::

Output:

But when we do ::: {.column width="50%" .incremental} for both columns, it still doesn't work. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to create a two column layout with an incremental option?

you can use ::: {.column width="50%" .fragment} instead of .incremental.

.incremental should work using this:
---
format: revealjs
---

# Example slide

:::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="50%" .incremental}
- Eat spaghetti
- Drink wine
:::

::: {.column width="50%" .incremental}
- Drink coffee
- Eat a hamburger
:::

::::


